# Combining multiple DataFrames and removing identical names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df1` that contains two columns, `n` and `MAE Linear`. I have another DataFrame `df2` that contains `n` and `MAE quadratic`.

Now, initially, I had a function called `getData(cash, forward, '4C', 'linear')` that would do some calculation and return the DataFrame that contains `n` and the type of interpolation I am doing.

Hence: `df1 = getData(cash, forward, '4C', 'linear')` and likewise for `df2 = getData(..., 'quadratic')`

Now, when I try `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`, I get `[n, MAE Linear, n, MAE quadratic]`.

How do I write it so that I only get `[n, MAE Linear, MAE quadratic]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two DataFrames on the column `n`:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='n', how='outer')
```

Here, a new DataFrame with the columns `n`, `MAE Linear`, `MAE quadratic` will be created, with the rows from `df1` and `df2` aligned on the values in the `n` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1.set_index('n', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('n', inplace=True)

joined = df1.join(df2)
```

Comment: I dont want to remove the index or set new indexes.  it messes up the format by rearranging everthing in a chronological manner.  is there any other way?  perhaps using concat or merge?

Comment: Yes, merge would be the way. I have up-voted the other answer for that reason.